# Configure rubymine with vagrant and rbenv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, development-environment, vagrant, rubymine, rbenv

I have a rails project with the following development environment:

- Host machine: MacOS 10.8
- Vagrant with precise 64
- Rubymine
- Rbenv

Everything works fine: rbenv is installed in the guest machine, and my rails server is started on port 3000 in the guest machine, and forwarded onto the host (config in Vagrant file).

I would like Rubymine (installed on the host machine) to use the SDK inside vagrant, and the gems inside Vagrant, and inside rbenv.

How can I do that ?

---

*To be clear:*

```
Host machine -> OSX
Guest machine -> Lucid64 in vagrant
```

Comment: `ctrl(or whatever replaces ctrl on mac)+alt+s` > `Add SDK` > `New remote` > `Fill from Vagrant config`?

Comment: @zrl3dx yep. The hard part was figuring out the right Ruby interpreter path.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In rubymine:

- go to options (command+`,`)
- search `SDK` in options,
- click `Add SDK` / `new remote`
- click `Fill from Vagrant config` and select the folder where your Vagrantfile is located
- **Very important**: In the field `Ruby interpreter path`, put `/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby` (your ruby version may change, check your versions with `ls /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions` in your guest machine
- Click OK, grab a cofee
- Your're done