# Rubymine 5.4.3.2.1 freezes sometimes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rubymine

I am using Rubymine to work on a suite of rails projects. There are quite a bit of gems and source files, but I think rubymine should be able to handle everything despite the size...

My sources files (and gems) are shared in a Vagrant box (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/19662310/311744).

Sometimes, when I am editing, Rubymine freezes. (about 5-6 seconds).

Usually, 3-4 minutes after I restart the IDE, everything is fine. Then I have one big 5 seconds freeze, and then from that point every 15-20 seconds I have a new freeze. During a freeze, Rubymine takes 100% (or a big part) of the CPU.

I am running on MacOS 10.8.5 on a recent MBPr.

I don't want to give up Rubymine. How can I troubleshoot that ?

Comment: There's a RubyMine 6.0 out. If your licence allows, upgrade for that. Couldn't hurt.

Comment: I upgraded to rubymine 6.0, and opened only projects which I work on.  And rubymine is fast again.

Answer (score 2):

In case of the performance issues you should start from the troubleshooting guides on the official support site:

- [thread dumps](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23348667)
- [CPU snapshots](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/29983118)
- [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23352446)

Check that all the files are local, try to [increase the heap size](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23395793) in case the problem is caused by the JVM garbage collection.

If nothing helps, provide all the collected data to the [technical support team](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/home/) or to the [issue tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RUBY).

Trying RubyMine 6.0 will definitely not hurt as noted in the comment above =)

**This guide is for all the users having performance issues with RubyMine or any other IntelliJ IDEA platform based IDE**.

Answer (score 0):

My situation (of freezing/hanging) was similar, while using RubyMine 2023, on a Mac.  For me felt like it happened more when dealing with Rspec tests.

In Settings/Preferences, turn off the synchronization with external file changes.  See this picture...
[image]

I suspect this can be for any of JetBrains IDEs (including IntelliJ - I am adding this keyword intentionally in case it helps others).